# How to modify a variable inside a lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am trying to do something like this:

```
def myFunc(y):
    aVariable = "a"
    bVariable = "b"
    y(aVariable,bVariable)

def main():
    myFunc(lambda a,b: a+=b)
```

and expecting the output to be `"ab"`.

Instead I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 7
  myFunc(lambda x, y: x += y)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why doesn't `myFunc` have a `return` statement? If you expect `y` to mutate `aVariable` &/or `bVariable` that's not going to happen, no matter what `y` does, because both `aVariable` & `bVariable` are strings, and Python strings are immutable.

Comment: Right you are, i change my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only [***expressions***](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) are allowed in the body of a `lambda` function; `a += b` is an [augmented assignment ***statement***](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), when compiled, this will lead to a `SyntaxError` as the grammar doesn't allow it.

You can either change it to simply return the addition:

```
lambda a,b: a+b
```

and then proceed to set the result of calling it to `a` appropriately:

```
a = y(aVariable,bVariable)
```

You could of course resort to using the function that is used for that operation. Though you could directly do `lambda a, b: a.__iadd__(b)`, this is clunky and using dunders like this isn't the best practice. Instead, you should use the appropriate operation from the `operator` module.

[The `iadd` function from `operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.iadd) allows you to bypass this "restriction" if you truly need to. *Function calls are **expressions***, as such, it is allowed to use them in the body of the lambda function. A simple `import` is needed:

```
from operator import iadd
```

and then, redefine the `lambda` passed to `myFunc` to use `iadd`:

```
myFunc(lambda a,b: iadd(a, b))
```

Adding these all together while also adding appropriate `return`s in `myFunc` and `main`:

```
from operator import iadd

def myFunc(y):
    aVariable = "a"
    bVariable = "b"
    return y(aVariable,bVariable)

def main():
    return myFunc(lambda a,b: iadd(a, b))
```

results in `ab` when `main` is called.